# How do i use threading in this program?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I've written this console application to search for a particular string from a file and see if its present or not.. But i want to open only the file in the main program. And include 10different threads to find 10 different words simultaneously.. I tried using the thread but i didnt get it right.. How do i do it? could someone help me with the code? This is my program..

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread T = new Thread(Finding);
        T.Start();
        using (System.IO.StreamReader Reader = new System.IO.StreamReader("C://myfile2.txt"))

        {
            StringBuilder Sb = new StringBuilder();
            string fileContent = Reader.ReadToEnd();
            if (fileContent.Contains("and"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("It is Present");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("It is not Present");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    static void Finding()
    {
        if (fileContent.Contains("hello"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("It is Present");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("It is not Present");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using 10 threads to find 10 words is far from the best way to achieve your goal. Is this homework?

Comment: @anthony 10 is just an example.. but it can go upto 100.. Could u just help me with one? i'll learn from it and do the rest? no its not homework.. Its a project i'm trying to do..

Comment: Read content and then start thread.

Comment: @Reniuz How do i do it? I'm not able to figure it out.. Can u help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var text = File.ReadAllText("somePath");

foreach (var word in new[]{"word1", "word2", "word3"})
{
    var w = word;

    new Thread(() => Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}",
                                       w,
                                       text.Contains(w) ? "Yes" : "No")).Start();
}
```

You should know that string can't contain infinite characters, so if the content is too big for a string, you could use File.ReadAllLines("path") into "lines" instead of File.ReadAllText("path") into "text" and replace

```
text.Contains(w)
```

with

```
lines.Any(l => l.Contains(w))
```

You could also do something sophisticated using File.ReadLines() to avoid reading all lines when not necessary, if you believe that all words are likely to be found.

Comment: @3692 Also, don't forget to check File.Exists("somePath") before any of that, to ensure no FileNotFound exception will be thrown.

Comment: Sure i will add that Nathan.. i really appreciate ur help.. :)